# React-Bootstrap menus do not show the current selection

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-nav

For example, in the next image, the menu selected was about, the address string shows it, but the menu tab is still showing home

[image]

I am a newbie with Bootstrap

The code is this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default function NavSample() {
    const [key, setKey] = useState('home');

    const handleSelect = (key) => {
        setKey(key);
    };

    return (
        <Nav variant="pills" activeKey="home" onSelect={handleSelect} defaultActiveKey="home">
            <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey="home" href="/home">
                    Home
                </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey="about" href="/about" title="about">
                    About
                </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey="contact" href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <NavDropdown title="Pricing" id="nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="Basic pricing" href="/pricing/basic pricing">Basic</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="Corporate Pricing" href="/pricing/corporate pricing">Corporates</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Divider />
                <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="Enterprise Pricing" href="/pricing/enterprise pricing">Enterprise</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
    );
}
```

What am I missing?

Rafael

Comment: you probably need to tie the `activeKey` in `<Nav>` to your `key` in state.

Comment: Hi tromgy, I did it, simply wrote eventKey={key}, and it is worst now, all tabs are now selected :(

Comment: no, it should be `activeKey` in `<Nav>`, and NOT `eventKey` in `<Nav.Link>`, but you've got another problem -- having those hrefs changing the route causes it reset the state every time. So even if you do set `activeKey`, the key will instantly get reset to "home" because the whole page gets reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to deal with state resets you need to use React router for your routes instead of just `href`s

You need to install **react-router-dom** and **react-router-bootstrap** packages as well.

Here's a working example:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

export default function NavTabs({ active_key }) {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(active_key);

  const handleSelect = (key) => {
    console.log(`selected ${key}`);
    setKey(key);
  };

  console.log(`Rendering with ${key}`);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav variant="pills" activeKey={key} onSelect={handleSelect}>
        <LinkContainer to="/home">
          <Nav.Link eventKey="home">Home</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/about">
          <Nav.Link eventKey="about" title="about">
            About
          </Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/contacts">
          <Nav.Link eventKey="contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <NavDropdown title="Pricing" id="nav-dropdown">
          <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="Basic pricing" href="/pricing/basic pricing">
            Basic
          </NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="Corporate Pricing" href="/pricing/corporate pricing">
            Corporates
          </NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item eventKey="Enterprise Pricing" href="/pricing/enterprise pricing">
            Enterprise
          </NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and when you use this component (e.g. from `<App>`), supply the starting tab:

```
function App() {
  return (<NavTabs active_key="home"/>)
}
```